# What's "a three-one decision"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard the phrase on a American radio. What does "a three-one decision" truly mean?

I figure there might be three people to make one decision. But i'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A three-one decision is a decision made through a majority vote and the result is 3 to 1. A majority vote happens when a committee or decision-making members of a group take a vote and follow the principle of majority ruling. So if a decision is made in favor of a proposal, basically you have three aye votes who are in favor and one nay vote who is against. If the decision went the other way, it means three nay votes against one aye vote. Either way, that is 3 to 1.

Comment: In speech, both "three one decision" and "three to one decision" are possible, right? The 'to' is optional to be pronounced?

Comment: @dan You got it.

Comment: This rule also applies the scoring system in sports, right?

Comment: @dan Yes. "to" is commonly omitted in sports too.